# Vue.js with Vuex: how do I wrap 3rd party libraries?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am making an app with Vue.js and I'm trying to understand how best to do things with Vuex. My application has a web map that can have editing enabled or disabled by the user. I use a third party library for web mapping.

Tutorials mention that we could wrap third party libraries to abstract them away. I don't want Vue components to do work directly with the e.g. `map` or `mapLayer` objects associated with the web mapping library. Instead they should just call a method or dispatch an action such as `this.$store.dispatch("startEditingLayerByName","layerName")` or `this.mapwrapper.startEditingLayerByName("layerName")`. When the map is in editing mode, Vue components change their appearance to indicate editing mode.

My current solution looks something like this:

```js
//MapWrapper.ts
export class MapWrapper {
    private map? : Map;

    public addLayer(layerName:string): void {
        // interactions with this.map object.
    }

    public stopEditingLayerByName(layerName:string) {
        // interactions with this.map object.        
    }

    public startEditingLayerByName(layerName:string) {
        // interactions with this.map object.
    }

    public initialiseMap(mapID:string) {

        const mapElement = document.getElementById(mapID);
        if (mapElement === null) {
            throw new Error(`No DOM element with ID: ${mapID}`);
        };

        this.map = new Map({
            target:mapID,
            layers: [
                LayerDefinitions.openStreetMap
            ],
            view: new View({
              center: fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
              zoom: 4
            })
        });
    }
}
```

```js
// MapStore.ts
    
const mapWrapper = new MapWrapper();
  

const MapStore = createStore({
    state (): {
        isMapEditing: false
    },
    mutations: {
        setMapEditingState(state,newEditingState) {
            state.isMapEditing = newEditingState;
        },
    },
    actions: {
        startEditingLayerByName(context,layerName) {
            // Here is the bad part. It would be better if MapWrapper decided whether to start editing or not based on its own internal state.
            if (context.state.isMapEditing === false ) { 
                mapWrapper.startEditingLayerByName("layerName");
                this.commit("setMapEditingState",true)
            }
        },
    },
});
```

```js
//mapComponent.vue
export default defineComponent({
    setup(props) {
        const mapService = inject('mapservice') as IMapService;
        return {
            mapService
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.mapService.initialiseMap("map");
    },    
});
```

```js
// startEditingButton.vue pseudocode

// When clicked, Button dispatches startEditingLayerByName action to MapState. 

// if this.$state.isMapEditing === true, button is disabled.
```

There are many other components like `startEditingButton.vue`. Some of them are quite deeply nested, so it'd be a lot of work to pass props all the way down to them. There will also be more variables associated with the map state in future. Therefore I use Vuex.

I need to stop editing from starting when the web map is already in editing mode, and I feel my approach (which matches option 1 below) is not ideal. I'd rather that the `MapWrapper` holds its own property `isEditing` rather than keeping it on the store.

In my mind, I have 3 choices:

1. Split the state between the wrappers and the Vuex store. So public state (e.g. isMapEditing) on the Vuex store, private state (e.g. `map`, `mapLayer`) in the wrappers. This seems not ideal to me, but possibly the best option. If we need to stop the `mapWrapper.startEditing` method from being called twice, then the store would need to decide whether to start editing, rather than the map wrapper deciding for itself based on its own state.
2. Remove the third party library wrappers and do all the work in the Vuex actions. This would mean that all the details of the library would be stored in the public Vuex state; not ideal.
3. Remove Vuex completely and do everything in the library wrappers. This is not ideal as then we won't benefit from the "reactiveness" of Vue.

What is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: The description isn't specific enough without some code. It's unclear what wrappers look like and why "we won't benefit from the "reactiveness" of Vue". Vuex isn't the only reactive thing in Vue and isn't needed a lot of times. It's really about global vs local state. The question doesn't contain a proof that you need global state for this. *and then this approach breaks down* - why? *This would mean that all the details of the library would be stored in the public Vuex state; not ideal* - not just ideal but wrong, the only case it's desirable is when you need to save/restore internal state.

Comment: @EstusFlask Apologies. I've edited now with some simplified code. Hopefully that clears things up. I use the Vuex state because there are a lot of components that need to share the state, and there will be a lot more global variables to store on the state than I describe in the problem above.

Comment: The service seems to be useless abstraction. It operates on DOM, this kind of code generally belongs to components, reusability is achieved by composing them. That you need reactivity in the service suggests that chosen implementation may be wrong. *a lot of components that need to share the state* - what state exactly? Is mapComponent.vue a parent of startEditingButton.vue ? Are there multiple maps simultaneously? Any way, what I said still applies, it's about global vs local state. If there's single edit mode state for the app, it can be stored in Vuex. Store things globally per need basis.

Comment: "It operates on DOM, this kind of code generally belongs to components reusability is achieved by composing them" - that was the kind of the answer I was looking for; I knew I was thinking about the problem wrong, but I just didn't know how. If you post that as the answer I will accept it. mapComponent is not a parent of startEditingButton; so there would be a lot of events to get them to communicate. Good question about multiple maps simultaneously, I hadn't considered that possibility.  I think moving to component + composition from the services will solve my issues.

Comment: @EstusFlask Writing a Vue component that directly calls things like `new Map()` makes testing difficult for me. I can't see how to test a component like this: I cannot mock a constructor, for instance, and I cannot put expectations on method calls. Possibly this is a case for a separate question, though.

Comment: I'll try to write the post soon. As for testing, this is expected for components. You can't put expectations on method calls with composition API, it forces testing the behaviour rather than implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. This part wasn't in the original question, so apologies, I will still accept your answer if you post; it was my oversight:- Testing the behaviour of a web map is quite difficult - they generally draw to canvas elements that might not even exist in the test environment. Would you say that wrapping the library is useful for cases like these?

Comment: Mocking third-party lib is a reasonable way to this in Jest alone with no headless browser involved, and the only proper way to do this in unit tests - they shouldn't be affected by libs that you don't own except the framework itself that has determined behaviour. You can test the real thing in e2e and visual regression test.